# Remove ?query=string from URL with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I used to have a query string for handling mobile pages. Now the site is responsive it doesn't need it and I need to do 301 redirects let google know.

so

http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb?fromMobile=true
should become
http://www.example.com/aaa/bbb

and

http://www.example.com/aaa?fromMobile=true
should become
http://www.example.com/bbb

and

http://www.example.com?fromMobile=true
should become
http://www.example.com

etc

I have:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?)fromMobile=true$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1&%2 [R=301,L]
```

But this redirects:

http://www.example.com?fromMobile=true
to
http://www.example.com?

How can I get rid of the trailing question mark? I've tried a bunch of things without joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fromMobile=true$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

This is assuming there is no other query parameter besides `fromMobile=true`.

If there is a chance of other query parameters also then use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?fromMobile=true(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```